# Spark number of tasks (partitions) is not equal to spark.default.parallelism

Tags: apache-spark

I build a spark cluster and submit application with standalone mode. My application only contains one stage, which read data from HDFS.

In some posts, it is recommended to set `spark.default.parallelism` parameters to 2~3 times to number of cores. In this sense, I set this parameters to 300 so that there are 300 partitions/tasks in each stage.
However, when I check the log, I find something like

```
Finished task 133.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 157) in 22236 ms on 166.111.74.114 (executor 1) (147/147)
```

I have some problems about this log:

1. Why my total task number is 147, instead of 300. I have checked `Enviroment` in `master:18080`, and the value of `spark.conf.parallelism` is 300 for sure.
2. Why is it "finished task 133.1", i.e., what does ".1" stand for?

I post the code that I used in the following. It simply filter rows that contains "target word".

```scala
package com.sparkApp

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object MyClass {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("spark://master:7077")
            .setAppName("FilterRow")

        val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);

        val targetWord = "target word"
        val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://master:9000/path-to-input")
        val items = lines.filter(x => x.split("\t").size >= 4)
            .map(x => x.split("\t")(3))
            .filter(x => x.contains(targetWord))
            .saveAsTextFile("hdfs://master:9000/path-to-output")

        sc.stop()
    }
}
```

I use the following submit command:

```sh
bin/spark-submit \
--class com.sparkApp.MyClass \
--master spark://master:7077 \
--executor-cores 4 \
--total-executor-cores 20 \
--executor-memory 4G \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=300 \
/path/to/SparkApp.jar
```

I also paste part of logging information:

```sh
21/08/18 00:40:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 17.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 20, 166.111.74.126, executor 3, partition 17, ANY, 7450 bytes)
21/08/18 00:40:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 66.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 5007 ms on 166.111.74.126 (executor 3) (1/147)
21/08/18 00:40:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 21, 166.111.74.114, executor 1, partition 18, ANY, 7450 bytes)
21/08/18 00:40:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18) in 1859 ms on 166.111.74.114 (executor 1) (2/147)
21/08/18 00:40:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 19.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 22, 166.111.74.126, executor 3, partition 19, ANY, 7450 bytes)
21/08/18 00:40:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 53.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 5408 ms on 166.111.74.126 (executor 3) (3/147)
...
21/08/18 00:41:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 146.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 158, 166.111.74.114, executor 2, partition 146, ANY, 7447 bytes)
21/08/18 00:41:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 146.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 158) in 3560 ms on 166.111.74.114 (executor 2) (146/147)
21/08/18 00:41:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 133.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 157) in 22236 ms on 166.111.74.114 (executor 1) (147/147)
```

Thanks ahead for your patience on this question.

Comment: pls show the code you used

Comment: @thebluephantom Hi, thanks for your reply. I have add my code, submit command and part of logging information.

Comment: What are the type, size, and number of blocks of your input file on HDFS?

Comment: @TailofGodzilla There are 59 text files in the input directory, each with a number of lines and about 200MB. I use `hdfs sfck` check the block information. It says that each text file has 1~5 blocks, and there are 151 blocks in total.

Comment: That is weird, Are you sure about 151 blocks? I expect 147 blocks :)

Moreover, AFAIK the "spark.default.parallelism" is used to set the default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set by the user.

Try this one instead: sc.textFile("hdfs://master:9000/path-to-input", 300)

Comment: @TailofGodzilla Thanks for keeping up with this thread, and your solution really worked! I also feel surprised about the number of blocks. After I did as your suggested, the number of tasks became 324 (neither twice of 147 nor 151).

Comment: BTW, I did not use reduceByKey or join, etc., and but directly write filter results to hdfs. I think this may reason why parallelism parameter from command line does not work.

Comment: seealso https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html